# Can't use breakpoints in code::blocks even when debug settings are correct, linux

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

I've been trying to debug an error in a port of a console game I've made using code::blocks. But the breakpoint will just NOT stop at the breakpoint I set. I looked around the web and made sure -g was checked and -s was off. I've also checked around here and couldn't find anything quite the same as my error. Everything appears to work perfectly until the breakpoint is set. I'm using Linux Mint to develop. Here's the log:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Build succeeded
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: /home/jake/C++ Projects/TichHoe2/
Adding source dir: /home/jake/C++ Projects/TichHoe2/
Adding file: bin/Debug/TichHoe2
Starting debugger: 
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.02
Error in re-setting breakpoint 2: Function "/home/jake/C++     Projects/TichHoe2/Board.h:108" not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if there is a space in your build path (in your case "c++  projects").
Just rename that directory or move the project to a place where there are no spaces in your path.

Reason:
Ref this link: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#Path_with_spaces

You may have to clean and build your project again